# Configuration file for training jobs

Tags: google-cloud-ml

The [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/jobs/submit/training) `ml-engine jobs submit training` accepts a `--config` flag that identifies a configuration file for the job. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs), many fields of this file are "Output only". I assume this means that the fields are set by the ML Engine.

How do you write the configuration file so that the ML Engine will set these "Output only" fields? I've rewritten my file a few times, but I get an error when I run my application.

If anyone has any example configuration files, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one example of how to modify the worker types and counts, taken from the [criteo_tft](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/criteo_tft/config-large.yaml) sample:

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: large_model
  workerType: complex_model_m
  parameterServerType: large_model
  workerCount: 60
  parameterServerCount: 29
```

You'll find another example for Hyperparameter tuning, taken from the [Census sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/795aac91ecb58c6fcc7529d4d63f7b9186febe4d/census/hptuning_config.yaml).

Comment: Would you know what values one can set for `workerCount` and `parameterServerCount`?

Comment: Both workerCount and parameterServerCount can be 0 and they can go up to as high as you have quota for which depends on various factors. You can probably generally get 100+ machines (sum of workerCount+parameterServerCount). That said, YMMV with how much benefit you get from additional workers. If your model is amenable to using GPUs -- get 1 machine with as many GPUs as possible. Otherwise, if your model is highly parallelizable and works well on CPU, try 20 workers to start.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer. By machine do you mean the `parameterServerCount`?

Comment: WorkerCount. Figuring out the best ratio of parameter servers to workers is an art, not a science. Start with 7.